# How do I update the password for a Cognos Data Source?

Tags: passwords, cognos, datasource

The db password expired and it needs to be updated, how do I update the password for a Cognos Data Source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Cognos Administration, under Configuration tab, the Data Source Connections section (on the left):

Clicking on the Data Source name will bring give you the *Connection* for that Data Source (the Connection might have the same name as the Data Source). Clicking on **that** will bring you to the *Signon* (Which may also have the same name, it is an icon of a db with a user icon next to it). Choose properties of the Signon, on the properties page select the signon tab, on that page is an entry to "Edit the signon".